# cordapp-example on a VM does not appear to start correctly

Tags: corda

I'm attempting to deploy cordapp-example to a Google Compute Engine VM (Ubuntu 16.04). I *am* using OpenJDK (I know but I'm not able to use the Oracle JDK). I've attempted to follow the pre-reqs.

However, I think at least one problem results from the advice to "Do not click while 8 additional terminal windows start up." (this isn't going to occur through ssh'ing to a remote VM).

`runnodes` never results in `Webserver started up in XX.X sec` or `Node for “NodeC” started up and registered in XX.XX sec` and (therefore) does not result in a process listening on :10007.

Console output:

```
Starting nodes in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes
Starting corda.jar in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyB on debug port 5005
Starting corda-webserver.jar in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyB on debug port 5006
Starting corda.jar in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/Controller on debug port 5007
Starting corda.jar in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyC on debug port 5008
Starting corda-webserver.jar in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyC on debug port 5009
Starting corda.jar in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyA on debug port 5010
Starting corda-webserver.jar in /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyA on debug port 5011
Started 7 processes
Finished starting nodes
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5011
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5009
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5006
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5008
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5010
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5007
Unknown command line arguments: no-local-shell is not a recognized option
Unknown command line arguments: no-local-shell is not a recognized option
Unknown command line arguments: no-local-shell is not a recognized option


   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         I had an account with a bank in the
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          North Pole, but they froze all my assets 
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 1.0.0 (31be2a4) -----------------------------------------------



   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         I had an account with a bank in the
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          North Pole, but they froze all my assets 
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 1.0.0 (31be2a4) -----------------------------------------------




   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         What you can buy for a dollar these
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          days is absolute non-cents! 
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 1.0.0 (31be2a4) -----------------------------------------------




   ______               __
  / ____/     _________/ /___ _
 / /     __  / ___/ __  / __ `/         It's not who you know, it's who you know
/ /___  /_/ / /  / /_/ / /_/ /          knows what you know you know.
\____/     /_/   \__,_/\__,_/

--- Corda Open Source 1.0.0 (31be2a4) -----------------------------------------------



Logs can be found in                    : /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyA/logs
Logs can be found in                    : /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyB/logs
Logs can be found in                    : /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/Controller/logs
Logs can be found in                    : /home/dazwilkin/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyC/logs
Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://10.138.0.5:33219/node
Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://10.138.0.5:41313/node
Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://10.138.0.5:36079/node
Database connection url is              : jdbc:h2:tcp://10.138.0.5:38015/node
Incoming connection address             : localhost:10002
Incoming connection address             : localhost:10008
Incoming connection address             : localhost:10005
Incoming connection address             : localhost:10011
Listening on port                       : 10002
RPC service listening on port           : 10003
Providing network services              : corda.notary.validating
Loaded CorDapps                         : kotlin-source-0.1, corda-finance-1.0.0, corda-core-1.0.0
Node for "Controller" started up and registered in 46.26 sec
Listening on port                       : 10008
RPC service listening on port           : 10009
Listening on port                       : 10011
RPC service listening on port           : 10012
Listening on port                       : 10005
RPC service listening on port           : 10006
Loaded CorDapps                         : kotlin-source-0.1, corda-finance-1.0.0, corda-core-1.0.0
Node for "PartyB" started up and registered in 51.99 sec
Loaded CorDapps                         : kotlin-source-0.1, corda-finance-1.0.0, corda-core-1.0.0
Node for "PartyC" started up and registered in 52.75 sec
Loaded CorDapps                         : kotlin-source-0.1, corda-finance-1.0.0, corda-core-1.0.0
Node for "PartyA" started up and registered in 53.48 sec
```

and `ss --tcp --listening` filtered and sorted results in:

```
 *:5005
 *:5007
 *:5008
 *:5010
 *:ssh
:::10002
:::10003
:::10005
:::10006
:::10008
:::10009
:::10011
:::10012
:::33219
:::36079
:::38015
:::41313
:::ssh
```

For what it's worth:

- the debug ports aren't reported by ss: 5006, 5009, 5011
- there's no reference by ss to 10007 being used; can't browse to it
- this error looks not good `no-local-shell is not a recognized option`

It's unclear to me what I can debug. `runnodes` is opaque and I don't see obvious errors suggesting nodes are missing.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

P.S. There do appear to be 8 java processes running 4 of which include a flag `--no-local-shell` so perhaps that's a difference with OpenJDK and perhaps a|the problem?

Comment: Which shell are you running against ? It may be the case that the runnodes script needs a tweak...

Comment: Thanks @RichardGreen I'm using bash. `runnodes` appears to mostly just wrap a call `java -jar runnodes.jar` which is opaque to me. Any help you can provide would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also experienced this issue. It's something I'm looking into but in the meantime, a simple workaround is to run the webservers manually by running the following in the nodes directory (kotlin-source/build/nodes I think?):

```
find . -name corda-webserver.jar -execdir sh -c 'java -jar {} &' \;
```

As an aside, Corda is tested against the Azul build of OpenJDK in addition to Oracle JDK. I don't believe the problem is related to OpenJDK, I think it's a timing issue in the runnodes.jar.

Comment: it works, thank you... So I needed to run `runnodes` and then run your solution which (re-)executes the `corda-webserver.jar` for Party[A|B|C].